# How to generate a 78MHz clock

Tags: vhdl, frequency, fpga

I own a Digilent Nexys2 and I'm coding in VHDL, using Xilinx ISE ide.

I have to generate a very specific clock for my purpose, using the onboard DCM:
starting from a base clock of 50MHz, duty cycle = 50%, I need a 78MHz, duty cycle = 70%, output clock.

The main problem is that I didn't noticed any option to control the output duty cycle or other related things using the wizard. Am I missing something? Is there any solution or work around?

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it's not possible with the Spartan 3E (DCM).  With other components, e.g. the Kintex7 with the MMCME2_ADV, it is possible.

Comment: I see... is it legit to generate two phase shifted 39MHz, DC=50%, clocks, and then XOR them?
This way i'll have one 78MHz clock, with an appropriate DC

Comment: well, when I stated that it was not possible, I thought to write "not possible in a simple and clean way".  Can you not change the input DC?  If you don't request to the DCM to modify it back to 50%, you could have a change it stays at the input DC.

Comment: Actually I prefer a simple and a clean way to do this, my precedent post was only a suggestion.
unfortunately i can't change the input DC as it is the system clock, and i should use it "as is".